# How do I add a picture to HTML Canvas, and upload it?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I've been following these tutorials: [sketch.js](http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/) and [upload picture to server](http://www.codicode.com/art/upload_and_save_a_canvas_image_to_the_server.aspx).

In the sketch.js HTML example, the picture is displaying and I can draw on the picture but when I save and upload what I have done, it only captures or save what I drew on the picture not the whole thing.

```
<canvas id="colors_sketch" width="800" height="300" style="background: url(http://farm1.static.flickr.com/91/239595759_3c3626b24a_b.jpg) no-repeat center center;" ></canvas>
<button onclick="javascript:UploadPic();return false;">Upload Picture to Server</button>
```

I'm thinking in sketch.js example maybe if i give a command to load the picture in sketch.js file instead in the html file, maybe it will capture or save the picture and what i drew on the picture.

**The question is**: where and what do I put in sketch.js file

```
var __slice = Array.prototype.slice;
(function($) {
  var Sketch;
  $.fn.sketch = function() {
    var args, key, sketch;
    key = arguments[0], args = 2 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 1) : [];
    if (this.length > 1) {
      $.error('Sketch.js can only be called on one element at a time.');
    }
    sketch = this.data('sketch');
    if (typeof key === 'string' && sketch) {
      if (sketch[key]) {
        if (typeof sketch[key] === 'function') {
          return sketch[key].apply(sketch, args);
        } else if (args.length === 0) {
          return sketch[key];
        } else if (args.length === 1) {
          return sketch[key] = args[0];
        }
      } else {
        return $.error('Sketch.js did not recognize the given command.');
      }
    } else if (sketch) {
      return sketch;
    } else {
      this.data('sketch', new Sketch(this.get(0), key));
      return this;
    }
  };
  Sketch = (function() {
    function Sketch(el, opts) {
      this.el = el;
      this.canvas = $(el);
      this.context = el.getContext('2d');
      this.options = $.extend({
        toolLinks: true,
        defaultTool: 'marker',
        defaultColor: '#000000',
        defaultSize: 5
      }, opts);
      this.painting = false;
      this.color = this.options.defaultColor;
      this.size = this.options.defaultSize;
      this.tool = this.options.defaultTool;
      this.actions = [];
      this.action = [];
      this.canvas.bind('click mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseleave mouseout touchstart touchmove touchend touchcancel', this.onEvent);
      if (this.options.toolLinks) {
        $('body').delegate("a[href=\"#" + (this.canvas.attr('id')) + "\"]", 'click', function(e) {
          var $canvas, $this, key, sketch, _i, _len, _ref;
          $this = $(this);
          $canvas = $($this.attr('href'));
          sketch = $canvas.data('sketch');
          _ref = ['color', 'size', 'tool'];
          for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
            key = _ref[_i];
            if ($this.attr("data-" + key)) {
              sketch.set(key, $(this).attr("data-" + key));
            }
          }
          if ($(this).attr('data-download')) {
            sketch.download($(this).attr('data-download'));
          }
          return false;
        });
      }
    }
    Sketch.prototype.download = function(format) {
      var mime;
      format || (format = "png");
      if (format === "jpg") {
        format = "jpeg";
      }
      mime = "image/" + format;
      return window.open(this.el.toDataURL(mime));
    };
    Sketch.prototype.set = function(key, value) {
      this[key] = value;
      return this.canvas.trigger("sketch.change" + key, value);
    };
    Sketch.prototype.startPainting = function() {
      this.painting = true;
      return this.action = {
        tool: this.tool,
        color: this.color,
        size: parseFloat(this.size),
        events: []
      };
    };
    Sketch.prototype.stopPainting = function() {
      if (this.action) {
        this.actions.push(this.action);
      }
      this.painting = false;
      this.action = null;
      return this.redraw();
    };
    Sketch.prototype.onEvent = function(e) {
      if (e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.targetTouches) {
        e.pageX = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX;
        e.pageY = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageY;
      }
      $.sketch.tools[$(this).data('sketch').tool].onEvent.call($(this).data('sketch'), e);
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    };
    Sketch.prototype.redraw = function() {
      var sketch;
      this.el.width = this.canvas.width();
      this.context = this.el.getContext('2d');
      sketch = this;
      $.each(this.actions, function() {
        if (this.tool) {
          return $.sketch.tools[this.tool].draw.call(sketch, this);
        }
      });
      if (this.painting && this.action) {
        return $.sketch.tools[this.action.tool].draw.call(sketch, this.action);
      }
    };
    return Sketch;
  })();
  $.sketch = {
    tools: {}
  };
  $.sketch.tools.marker = {
    onEvent: function(e) {
      switch (e.type) {
        case 'mousedown':
        case 'touchstart':
          this.startPainting();
          break;
        case 'mouseup':
        case 'mouseout':
        case 'mouseleave':
        case 'touchend':
        case 'touchcancel':
          this.stopPainting();
      }
      if (this.painting) {
        this.action.events.push({
          x: e.pageX - this.canvas.offset().left,
          y: e.pageY - this.canvas.offset().top,
          event: e.type
        });
        return this.redraw();
      }
    },
    draw: function(action) {
      var event, previous, _i, _len, _ref;
      this.context.lineJoin = "round";
      this.context.lineCap = "round";
      this.context.beginPath();
      this.context.moveTo(action.events[0].x, action.events[0].y);
      _ref = action.events;
      for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        event = _ref[_i];
        this.context.lineTo(event.x, event.y);
        previous = event;
      }
      this.context.strokeStyle = action.color;
      this.context.lineWidth = action.size;
      return this.context.stroke();
    }
  };
  return $.sketch.tools.eraser = {
    onEvent: function(e) {
      return $.sketch.tools.marker.onEvent.call(this, e);
    },
    draw: function(action) {
      var oldcomposite;
      oldcomposite = this.context.globalCompositeOperation;
      this.context.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
      action.color = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
      $.sketch.tools.marker.draw.call(this, action);
      return this.context.globalCompositeOperation = oldcomposite;
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

where can i insert the code below in sketch.js file

```
var image = new Image();
    image.src = 'Tooth18.jpg';
    $(image).load(function () {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    });
```

I also added this in sketch.js file to save and upload picture to server

```
function UploadPic() {

    // generate the image data
    var Pic = document.getElementById("colors_sketch").toDataURL("image/png");
    Pic = Pic.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "")

    // Sending the image data to Server
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Save_Picture.aspx/UploadPic',
        data: '{ "imageData" : "' + Pic + '" }',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("Done, Picture Uploaded."); 
        }
    });
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, ty.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use sketch.js, but from their website it looks like you feed it a canvas element to draw on.

Therefore if you draw an image plus sketches on that canvas you can later save the content with `context.toDataURL`.

You could put a button on your page to trigger your `UploadPic`.

In your Ajax POST, you don't want those curly-braces to be in quotes. The curly-braces define an object containing the `imgBase64` property.

```
data: { imageData: Pic },
```

Comment: i'm very much a noob in .js and Ajax... u mentioned that u dont use sketch.js what did you use? can u give me a link pls.... about the context.toDataURL can you elaborate more where in sketch.js i can do this....

Comment: In my "day job", we use native html canvas to make data visualization clearer and more easily understood by our clients. We also use d3 (an amazing SVG library!) for data visualization: http://d3js.org/, d3 is not directly applicable directly to sketching, but can be used to create invaluable sketching widgets. We have also coded proprietary freehand annotation tools in native canvas which include "sketching" capabilities. A good learning path is to keep working with the tool you've started with until it fails to meet needs. Then examine it's source code and alter it to meet needs. Good luck!